# Can't load UICollectionView from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

My `UITableViewController` has cells with build-in `UICollectionView`. I wound want to move `UIViceController` logic into the cell class - `JournalSceneCell`. To implement it in the controller I assigned to the cell's variable `imagesFilename` a new value

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = ... as? JournalSceneCell
    cell.imagesFilename = Array(journalRef!.entries[indexPath.row].imagesFilenames)
    return cell
}
```

The images could be large, and to make the UITableViewController load as fast as possible I tried to perform loading images in the `didSet` section and also use a background thread:

```
class JournalSceneCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var entryTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var desctiptionText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var shareButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var collectionViewRef: UICollectionView!

    convenience init() {
        self.init()
        self.collectionViewRef.dataSource = self
   }

    struct ImageEntry {
        var image:UIImage
        var imageURL:URL
    }

    let collectionCellID = "JournalCollectionCellID"

    var selectedImages = [ImageEntry]()

    var imagesFilename = [String]() {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                let documentURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                               in: .userDomainMask,
                                                               appropriateFor: nil,
                                                               create: true)
                self.selectedImages.removeAll()
                for imageName in self.imagesFilename {
                    let imageURL = documentURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName)
                    let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
                    let img = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                    self.selectedImages.append(ImageEntry(image: img, imageURL: imageURL))
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionViewRef.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return selectedImages.count
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionViewRef.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: collectionCellID,
                                                        for: indexPath) as? JournalCollectionCell else {
            fatalError("Cannot connect a collection cell")
        }

        cell.imageView.image = selectedImages[indexPath.row].image
        return cell

    }

}
```

The problem: JournalSceneCell does not call `collectionView` func from UICollectionViewDataSource at all. Everything is connected via IB, reuse identified was added, but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
   super.awakeFromNib()
   self.collectionViewRef.dataSource = self
   self.collectionViewRef.delegate = self
}
```

---

```
class JournalSceneCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {
```

Comment: Actually I tried it. It didn’t help. Also I don’t need the delegate

Comment: Why? This is images from the local gallery

Comment: sure your documents file has images or you need main bundle like `let img = UIImage(named: "name.png")!`

Comment: I checked it again - It has images

Answer (score 0):

### Reload collection view in tableView Cell,It will work

cell.collectionViewRef.reloadData()

Comment: I am going to try

Answer (score 0):

The `convenience init()` does not being called. 
Finally I solve the problem by adding a func `loadImages(fileNameArray:[String])` into`JournalSceneCell`:

```
func loadImages(fileNameArray:[String]) {
    self.imageSetView.dataSource = self
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let documentURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                       in: .userDomainMask,
                                                       appropriateFor: nil,
                                                       create: true)
        self.selectedImages.removeAll()
        for imageName in fileNameArray {
            let imageURL = documentURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName)
            let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
            let img = UIImage(data: imageData)!
            self.selectedImages.append(ImageEntry(image: img, imageURL: imageURL))
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.imageSetView.reloadData()
        }

    }
}
```

Later I just called it from `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = .. as? JournalSceneCell,
    cell.loadImages(fileNameArray:Array({...}))
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and it was because the `UICollectionView` wasn't even being drawn in the `UITableViewCell`, so I had to set a minimum height `NSLayoutConstraint` on the collection view.

You probably need the height of the `UICollectionView` to be dynamic though, in this case, but I'm not entirely sure your best route for that.

Comment: I am going to try. It was connected and constructed via InterfaceBuilder, but maybe something went wrong.